# How I can make a table in database having variable columns in Java?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a Java web application. I have to create a table, and I am using JDBC.

I don't know in my list tag how many values will be there, so for each value tag, I need a corresponding column in my table. These values are fetched from some other application.

So I can create a table having *n* number of columns where *n* can be different every time.

```
<list>
<value>Name</value>
<value>Address</value>
<value>Contact No</value>
..
.
.
</list >
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What database are you using?  What is the maxmimum length of your values? A VARCHAR or CLOB column type will be suitable but it depends on the database and the length of your values.

Comment: I am using Oracle Databasse..All are varchar2(30)..

Comment: Are you trying to create a table based on the values in the list? Or are you trying to select columns from an already created table? As per the question it looks like you are trying to create.. if you are, then you will need to use a create table statement and include the columns as specified in the list. How about the column type? How about the primary keys? How about indexes? Are trying to write an app that will manage a database for you?

Comment: On another note.. if you think your table can take any form based on values from another app, then its best you dont use an RDBMS at all. Try SimpleDB or NO SQL DB which are mostly key value pairs.. Check this link:http://neo4j.org/

Comment: there are no primary keys..no indexes..all are varchar2(30)...suppose if list tag contains..                                                < list > < value >Name< /value > < value >Address< /value > < /list >  then my table should have 2 columns of name and addresses..

Comment: Then ideal candidate for a NOSQL db.. If you have to use an RDBMS then construct a create table statement dynamically based on the list.. and then execute it over JDBC..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to deal with your table structure dynamically. Several solutions exist.

With JDBC, simply query Oracle and retrieve the columns of your table.

```
String myTable = "FOO_TABLE";
String query = "Select COLUMN_NAME from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, myTable);
//
Set<String> existingColumns = new HashSet<String>();
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next())
{
    existingColumns.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Now you know which column exists or not and you can `ALTER` your table as you want.

Comment: While this is technically possible, I doubt an application should dynamically alter database tables

Comment: I don't think so. An update phase that upgrade the version of a database schema is plausible (within an ERP app for example), your down vote is offensive. Your answer is an advice, and not a response to the question.

Comment: I agree about the update phase, but this is not the 'normal' operation of an application. If you dynamically create/alter database tables, you also have to access them dynamically (code generation perhaps?), this means you implement an overly complex key/value storage.

Comment: Thank you for your agreement... But your down vote is still **inappropriate and offensive**.
What an app do, the way it do it: this is not your business.
Of course it's better to apply a fifth normal form, and design a DB schema otherwise but it's not the point.

Comment: @michael667 -- But before putting up a select query i want a create query to create a table ..please make me understand your answer..

Comment: @viki I meant you should create a table by designing a database structure and writing a create table statement _manually_, not as part of your application.

Comment: Note: The above, while it will work, is Oracle-specific. JDBC has a standard mechanism for retrieving database metadata, java.sql.DatabaseMetaData (getTable() etc.). It's usually better to use this, to avoid tying yourself to one database.

Answer (score 1):

You should use *n* rows to store the values, not *n* columns. Columns are somehow 'fixed' in a database, while it is easy to add/delete/modify rows.